# In javascript "contructor --> prototype" chain is never ending

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, prototype

While debugging the JavaScript prototype chain I came across that when we define a Constructor function, the constructor-->prototype chain is never-ending, it keeps on expanding. I have attached a screenshot and a sample code also for reference.
[image]

```
function Person(first, last, age, gender, interests) {
this.name = {
'first': first,
'last' : last
 };
 this.age = age;
this.gender = gender;
} 

const person1 = new Person("foo", "bar", 24, "Male")
```

My question is, does JavaScript access it by reference/walking up the chain or is JavaScript actually storing it in memory

Comment: There's no "Chain", there... You ran into a circular reference.

Answer (score 7):

The chain is not ever-expanding, it contains a circular reference.

As explained on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes#the_constructor_property):

> Every constructor function has a `prototype` property whose value is
> an object containing a [`constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) property. This `constructor`
> property points to the original constructor function.

The following example demonstrates this:

```js
function X() {}

const x = new X();

// test for strict equality
console.log(x.constructor === x.constructor.prototype.constructor); // true
```

Comment: Simple example: `function X() {}; x = new X(); x.constructor === x.constructor.prototype.constructor`

Comment: Got it thanks!
But as mentioned here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management , circular references would lead to a common cause of memory leaks. So does it consume huge amount of memory?

Comment: Why would this specific case result in memory leaks? This is how JS works, it's standard functionality. Any engine where this circular reference results in a memory leak will never work...

Comment: The link you posted explains that a reference-counting garbage collector could run into such an issue. Continue reading that article and note that *"[a]s of 2012, all modern browsers ship a mark-and-sweep garbage-collector."*